# POST gets null value

Tags: asp.net, rest

I don't know the exact format of the incoming JSON and have no control of it. I eventually need an object to match the incoming JSON format.

My thought was to treat it as a string and write it to a file, whatever format it is, so I can examine it and create an object to match.

From Fiddler, I'm sending this:

URL: https://localhost:44351/api/values

Headers

```
 User-Agent: Fiddler
 Host: localhost:44351
 Content-Length: 13
 Content-Type: application/json
```

Body

```
 {name='test'}
```

'Get' works and returns properly. 'Post' gets called but when I debug it, it gets a null value for the string.
It creates the file but, understandably, it is empty.

```
public class ValuesController: ApiController
{
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value=" + id.ToString();
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] string value)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\Import.txt", value);
        return Ok();
    }
```

or

```
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] GenericText value)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\Import.txt", value.Name);
        return Ok();
    }

    public class GenericText
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Routing

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

How do I get access to the incoming JSON so I can write it out to the file?

Answer (score 1):

You are posting a json object: `{name='test'}` and expect the body to be of type `string` in the controller. There are two possible solutions to your problem:

1. post a string and keep expecting a string in the controller.
2. keep posting the json object with the property `name` of type `string`, and change the expected type in the controller.

which would look like:

```cs
public class MyRequestObject
{
     public string Name {get;set;}
}

public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] MyRequestObject value)
{
     File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\Import.txt", value.Name);
     return Ok();
}
```

Comment: I don't know the exact format of the incoming JSON and have no control of it. I need to write an object to match the format. So I wanted to write it out, whatever format it is, to a file so I can examine it and create an object to match.

Comment: This seemed like a reasonable guess, but it still gets passed a null.

Comment: @BWhite if you're uncertain of the JSON format you should probably first consume the endpoint through a testing tool like [postman](https://www.postman.com/) or [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/). Feel free to update the post so I can assist further.

(ps. some IDE's like rider have this tool built-in: tools->HTTP Client)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Seems like that would make sense for a Get, if I didn't know what JSON would be returned. But since I'm writing the web service, even that doesn't make sense. I am using Fiddler in place of Postman to exercise the API so there's that. Once I can retrieve any incoming data, I can get it when I have the actual provider send the actual JSON. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: I'm trying another approach that isn't working either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68450825/modelbinding-not-executing

Comment: @BWhite in that case, try changing the type of value in the controller method to `object`. That's the most generic type that should result in a value (most likely a dictionary of string JObject).

Answer (score 0):

I never did solve this directly, but was able to work around it.

If your controller descends from Controller, you get access to Request

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the HttpRequestBase object for the current HTTP request.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The request object.
    public HttpRequestBase Request { get; }
```

I used it like so

```
    value = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Note that in some cases you need to reset the input stream to the beginning to be able to read any content, but I didn't need that step in the final solution.